# How do I increment value in textfield?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

im new to iphone, i have a two button left and right when i click left button to decrease the value in textfield and then i click right button to increase the value in textfield in iphone.
please any one help me.

left button (num1.tag=10)

```
text1.text=[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",num2.tag-1];
```

right button (num2.tag=11)

```
text1.text=[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",num2.tag];
```

Comment: or u can connect the buttons to different method.(ie)one method which increase value and put the value in textfield and another to decrease and display

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
- (void) btnAction :(id) sender
 {
       if ([sender tag] == 10) //left button
       {
             int aNumber = [[text1 text] intValue];
             aNumber = aNumber - 1 ;
             text1.text=[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",aNumber];
       }
       else if ([sender tag] == 11) //Right button
       {
            int aNumber = [[text1 text] intValue];
            aNumber = aNumber + 1 ;
            text1.text=[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",aNumber];
       }
 }
```

Comment: plz format my answer... I could not format it because  : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111348/formatting-tool-bar-not-shown-at-stack-overflow

Comment: @user1006445 : you have to take care of '0' on submission...put proper validation to check '0'

Answer (score 0):

convert the textValue to int and perform ur action

```
if(leftButton)
{
int newVal=[text1.text.text intValue]-1;
 text1.text=[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",newVal];

}
else 
{
int newVal=[text1.text.text intValue]+1;
 text1.text=[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",newVal];
}
```